# EXTJS : Access the cells of a TreePanel

Tags: extjs4

How do i access the cells in tree grid panel.

Visit http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/tree/treegrid/ to see the sample TreePanel.
How do i access the cells under "Duration" or "Assigned To" columns.

Comment: what do you mean by access exactly? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the value inside the cells of the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want the data returned in, here's a way to get data from a grid's store:

```
store.getAt(1).get("user")
```

Would get you the value at row index 1 for the column with dataIndex "user".